# Expected length of stick broken at two points using calculus

Tags: probability, expected-value

This question is from 50 problems in probability.

**Q.** *A glass rod is coloured red at one end and blue at other. Many such rods got broken into 3 parts. What is the average length of part colored blue*

---

The author argues that the answer should be *one third* as all things being symmetric the average length of each part must be equal. This seems alright

I tried using calculus maybe incorrectly. I denote length of rod as $1$ unit then let us suppose length of blue rod is $x$. Then probability of other point of breaking must be $1-x$. Expected length will be

$$\int p(x) x\, dx = \int_0^1 (1-x)x \, dx = \frac{1}{6}$$

This is wrong. But what is the error. I think the error is that when writing $p(x)$ I forget to normalise it, that is $\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)N\, dx = 1 \implies N = 2$. So multiplying by this factor fixes the probability and we get $1/3$.

Is this correct

Comment: I can't quite follow what you're trying to do with your integral, so unfortunately I can't explain why it's not right.

Comment: @BrianTung What I mean is that probability of blue part getting length $x$ is not $p(x) = 1-x$ but it is $2(1-x)$. This because $\int_0^1 p(x) dx$ must be $1$ so I multiplied by normalise factor $2$..

Comment: > all things being symmetric the average length of each part must be equal
That would be a good argument to show that the blue part and  the red part should have the same average length. That that applies also to the middle segment... no, that's not obvious, and the symmetry is not evident to me.

Answer (score 2):

To me it is not obvious that the average length of each part is ${1\over3}$, even if the two cuts are assumed independently uniformly distributed. Note that there are two independent cuts at points $x$ and $y$ in the interval $[0,1]$. When the first cut is at $x$ you have no idea at which point $y$ the second cut would be. In particular there is no question of enforced $y=1-x$.

But we can compute it. Assume the rod to be $[0,1]$, and that it is cut at two independently uniformly placed points $x$, $y\in[0,1]$. We may assume that the end at $0$ is colored blue. The length of the blue part then is $$\min\{x,y\}=\left\{\eqalign{u\qquad&(v>u)\cr v\qquad&(v<u)\cr}\right.$$

Since $(x,y)$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]^2$ the expected length of the blue part then is
$$E=\int_0^1\int_u^1 u\>dv\>du+\int_0^1\int_0^u v\>dv\>du={1\over3}\ .$$

Comment: I understand this, much appreciated, can you give advice about my proceeding also, thank you